# How does Earley parsing using an automaton work?

Tags: algorithms, automata, parsers

As described in [this paper](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs421/sp2012/project/PracticalEarleyParsing.pdf), you can use an pre-computed automaton to speed up an Earley parse.  I'm not interested in the rigorous proof of this, but just how the basic algorithm works so that I can implement it.  Understanding this paper on my own would take a long long time, and I don't think it's justified for this algorithm because it seems simple enough, but the paper is accademic and is required to be over my head, so they didn't write it for a reader like me.

For instance, what does a transition labeled with a variable in the automaton mean?  How does this thing work?

Comment: This paper is technically complicated, while the problem it addresses
is quite simple. Why do you want to have things explained in the
framework of this paper, rather than read a simpler account of how to
build such parsers. If you state your purpose ... why you want to
implement it for, I may be able to better answer you. Did you look at
reference 19 for example. It shows how to do "Earley-like" parsing
with any kind of non-deterministic pushdown automation. It has to be expressed with the given primitives operations, but that is easy.

Comment: You need to know what an automaton is before anyone can answer your question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine.